# Haskell lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

If I call the following Haskell code

```
find_first_occurrence :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
find_first_occurrence elem list = (snd . head) [x | x <- zip list [0..], fst x == elem]
```

with the arguments

```
'X' "abcdXkjdkljklfjdlfksjdljjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
```

how much of the zipped list `[('a',0), ('b',1), ]` is going to be built?

UPDATE:

I tried to run

```
find_first_occurrence 10 [1..]
```

and returns `9` almost instantly, so I guess it does use lazy evaluation at least for simple cases? The answer is also computed "instantly" when I run

```
let f n = 100 - n
find_first_occurrence 10 (map f [1..])
```

Comment: Correction: second expression should have 'X' in front, not 'x'.

Comment: Re "I guess it does use lazy evaluation at least for simple cases": Haskell uses lazy evaluation for *all* cases; the only exception is in the presence of `seq`.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, another exception is pattern matching, right?

Comment: @Rotsor: I'm not sure about it, Haskell in general may be able to pattern match an expression without actually fully evaluating it. `case zip [1..] [2..] of (a,b):_ -> True` evaluates to `True`, because we only need the first element of the list to match with `(a,b):_`.

Comment: @Rotsor BangPatterns yes; pattern matching a strict data constructor yes; but not in the normal case. What did you mean?

Comment: @dave4420, I thought pattern matching against any data constructor makes your function strict in the parameter you are matching. What are "non-strict" data constructors then?

Comment: @Riccardo, `case undefined of _:_ -> True; [] -> True` crashes while `(x -> True) undefined` yields True. The first one is stricter than the second one. Why is that if not because of the pattern match?

Comment: @Rotsor `x` is irrefutable pattern, so forces nothing; `(_:_)` checks if it is matched against a non-empty list. Strict data constructor would evaluate its arguments when the value is being created, not at the point of pattern match. The latter might trigger the creation though. And `seq` by itself forces nothing, only pattern-match does.

Comment: @Rotsor Pattern-matching is what drives evaluation, but saying that Haskell doesn't use laziness when doing pattern matching would be very misleading. Whether you match `foo` against the pattern `x`, or `_:_`, or `(_:_):_`, the runtime won't evaluate `foo` any farther than it needs to to decide which pattern matches.

Comment: @DanielWagner, indeed. And `seq x y`, similarly, will only evaluate `x` enough to determine its data constructor, showing that `seq` is exactly as lazy as a pattern match of a single constructor. If you don't consider the latter an exception, the first isn't an exception either.

Comment: @Rotsor I consider `seq` a special case because it works even on abstract data types, where you can't do pattern matching and hence can't drive evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of it.

Since StackOverflow won't let me post such a short answer: you can't get away with doing less work than looking through the whole list if the thing you're looking for isn't there.

Edit: The question now asks something much more interesting. The short answer is that we will build the list:

```
('a',0):('b',1):('c',2):('d',3):('X',4):<thunk>
```

(Actually, this answer is just the slightest bit subtle. Your type signature uses the monomorphic return type `Int`, which is strict in basically all operations, so all the numbers in the tuples above will be fully evaluated. There are certainly implementations of `Num` for which you would get something with more thunks, though.)

Comment: But I'm only looking for the first occurrence of 'x'. Not for the last one. Once I've found 'x', I don't need to analyze the rest of the list. Does lazy evaluation buy me that, or should I make the code smarter?

Comment: @quant_dev if 'x' is not on the list (like in your example, note that 'x' /= 'X') then looking up the first occurence will scan though whole list . If 'x' is on the list the evaluation will stop once the first 'x' is encountered.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to put 'X' there, not 'x'. It didn't make any sense with my error.

Comment: Okay, updating my answer to the new, more interesting question.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a Haskell newbie, so does you answer say "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: @quant_dev I'm not sure; the question as stated doesn't seem to be a yes-or-no question.

Comment: I updated my question to add the results of two tests with infinite lists. Do they make it easier to answer?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: it will be built only up to the element you're searching for. This means that only in the worst case you'll need to build the whole list, that is when no element satisfies the conditions.

Long answer: let me explain why with a pair of examples:

```
ghci> head [a | (a,b) <- zip [1..] [1..], a > 10]
11
```

In this case, zip should produce an infinite list, however the laziness enables Haskell to build it only up to `(11,11)`: as you can see, the execution does not diverge but actually gives us the correct answer.

Now, let me consider another issue:

```
ghci> find_first_occurrence 1 [0, 0, 1 `div` 0, 1]
*** Exception: divide by zero
ghci> find_first_occurrence 1 [0, 1, 1 `div` 0, 0]
1
it :: Int
(0.02 secs, 1577136 bytes)
```

Since the whole zipped list is not built, haskell obviously will not even evaluate each expression occurring in the list, so when the element is before `div 1 0`, the function is correctly evaluated without raising exceptions: the division by zero did not occur.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily answer such a question by introducing `undefined`s here and there. In our case it is sufficient to change our inputs:

```
find_first_occurrence 'X' ("abcdX" ++ undefined)
```

You can see that it produces the result, which means that it does not even look beyond the 'X' it found (otherwise it would have thrown an Exception). Obviously, the zipped list can not be built without looking at the original list.

Another (possibly less reliable) way to analyse your laziness is to use `trace` function from `Debug.Trace`:

```
> let find_first_occurrence elem list = (snd . head) [x | x <- map (\i -> trace (show i) i) $ zip list [0..], fst x == elem]
> find_first_occurrence 'X' "abcdXkjdkljklfjdlfksjdljjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
```

Prints

```
('a',0)
('b',1)
('c',2)
('d',3)
('X',4)
4
```